# How can i use AND(&&) operator in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can i use one click event for two different type of elements
here is my code that does not work.

```
$('li. selectable a')&&('td.selectable a').click(function() { .... });
```

Comment: Yep, this is also not correct syntax, as the AND operator is (AFAIK) at least in javascript, a boolean operator. You have to use the built-in function and specify multiple selectors, separated by commas.

Answer (score 9):

Change the selector to select both:

```
$("li.selectable a, td.selectable a").click(...
```

Comment: should be mentioned that things like datetimepicker rarely function with multiple selection.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Also known as the comma.

```
$('li.selectable a, td.selectable a').click(function() {
```

Of course you could here reduce this to

```
$('.selectable a').click(function() {
```

This would, however, be slightly slower in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Comma does not work?

```
$('li.selectable a, td.selectable a').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a comma:

```
$('li. selectable a, td.selectable a').click(function() {
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Or more up to date:

```
$('li.selectable a, td.selectable a').on('click', function() {
    // Execute code...
)};
```

Comment: This doesn't add any value to the question. The answer is still the same, use the correct selector; using `.on` vs `.click` makes no difference here, it may as well have been `.remove` or `.show`